# Cannot build maven application on Jenkins with JDK1.5

Tags: jenkins, maven-2, java-5

I am trying to build a maven 2.2.1 project on Jenkins ver. 1.596. The project uses JDK 1.5 and it is not an option to upgrade to a newer JDK.

When building the project I get the following stacktrace:

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: Bad version number in .class file
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:621)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:124)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:260)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:56)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:195)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:188)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:307)
    at org.codehaus.classworlds.RealmClassLoader.loadClassDirect(RealmClassLoader.java:195)
    at org.codehaus.classworlds.DefaultClassRealm.loadClass(DefaultClassRealm.java:255)
    at hudson.maven.agent.Main.main(Main.java:143)
    at hudson.maven.agent.Main.main(Main.java:68)

I have seen a lot of posts about this issue with Jenkins and JDK1.5, but noone has come up with a solution. Hope that somebody has found a workaround.

Regards
Steffen

Comment: Are you trying to run Jenkins with Java 1.5 ?  If so, that's not necessary to build a Java 1.5 project - let me know and I can post an answer.

Comment: I found a solution. Make a free-style project and call maven 2.2.1 in a windows batch command. You might have to start the shell command with "set maven_opts = ..." and then on the next line "(path to maven)\mvn clean install". Then it will work with JDK 1.5.